# Why my "pull down to load data" stuck at page 2 without loading anymore data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview, infinite-scroll

Is there a theory about reloading new data by appending old data with new from json?I am having problem with solving that case.I used [this infinite uitableview](https://github.com/i-schuetz/tableview_infinite) to reload more data from my api json string.My Api give me back the results base on page no.

My json header include "totalCount","currentPage" & "toPage" as it was describe in the below code."totalCount" means the total results that i am going to get.But,it gives me 15 results per page.So,if "totalCount" is 636.I have to go 43 pages(toPage).

Here is my code.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController,AuctionAPIProtocol{

var currentPage = 1
var currentCount = 0
var toPage = 0

var totalCount = 0

var api : AuctionAPI?
let cellId = "cell"

@IBOutlet var tableViewFooter:MyFooter! //Table Footer which was activity indicator

var items:[AuctionModel] = []//An empty array where items gonna store

var newItems:[AuctionModel] = []

var loading = false // Loading State for activity indicator


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    self.tableViewFooter.hidden = true
    api = AuctionAPI(delegate: self)
    api!.searchAuctionLatestFor("null",lotId: "1",page: "1")
}

//TableView Delegate and Datasource
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let item = items[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = item.vendorName.capitalizedString+"  "+item.modelName.capitalizedString+" "+item.year

    return cell
}


override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height
    // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
        if (maximumOffset - currentOffset) <= 40.0 {
            loadSegment(currentPage, count: items.count)
        }
}


func loadSegment(currentP:Int, count:Int) {

    //println("load segment current page: \(currentPage)")

    api = AuctionAPI(delegate: self)

    if (!self.loading) {

        self.setLoadingState(true)

        println("CP\(currentP)")
        println("TP\(count)")

        if currentPage < toPage{
            println("Enter Condition")
            var times = 0
            api!.searchAuctionLatestFor("null",lotId: "1",page: String(++currentPage))
            println("Current Page After API Call : \(currentPage)")

        }
        else if currentPage > toPage {
            setLoadingState(false)
        }
    }
    else{
        println("Not Loading")
    }

}

// Loading Progress at Table View Footer condition (disabling the table view footer which include loading indicator or not)
func setLoadingState(loading:Bool) {
    self.loading = loading
    self.tableViewFooter.hidden = !loading
}

func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary) {
    var resultsArr: NSArray = results["body"] as NSArray
    //fix
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.newItems = AuctionModel.latestWithJSON(resultsArr)
        println("Current Auction Items : \(self.newItems.count)")
        //println("Page: \(self.currentPage) Items \(self.items)")

        if self.currentPage > 1 {
                for item:AuctionModel in self.newItems {
                    self.items.append(item)
                }
        }
        else{
            self.items = self.newItems
        }

        self.currentCount = self.items.count

        println("After Auction Items : \(self.currentCount)")

        self.tableView?.reloadData()
        //Status bar network activity ကို ပိတ်​ရန်/ဖွင့်​ခဲ့​ရင်
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        self.tableView?.hidden = false
    })
}

func doSearchMoreAPIResults(results: JSON){
    if results != nil{
        totalCount = results["header"]["totalCount"].intValue
        currentPage = results["header"]["currentPage"].intValue
        toPage = results["header"]["toPage"].intValue
    }
    println("totalCount : \(totalCount)")
    println("currentPage : \(currentPage)")
    println("toPage : \(toPage)")
}

func didNotReceiveAPIResults(results: Bool){
    var connectionResult : Bool = results
}
}
```

AuctionAPI.swift

```
import Foundation

protocol AuctionAPIProtocol{
    func didReceiveAPIResults(results: NSDictionary)
    func didNotReceiveAPIResults(results: Bool)
    func doSearchMoreAPIResults(results:JSON)
}

class AuctionAPI{

var delegate: AuctionAPIProtocol
var urlParameterStringController:URLParameterStringController!

init(delegate: AuctionAPIProtocol){
    self.delegate=delegate
}

func post(path:String,params:Dictionary<String,String>){

    //Parameter Parts.....

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        .....
        self.delegate.didReceiveAPIResults(jsonData)
        self.delegate.doSearchMoreAPIResults(json)
    })
    task.resume()
}

func searchAuctionLatestFor(token:String,lotId:String,page:String){
    .....
    post(urlPath,params: params)
}
}
```

I updated the code,and now i am stuck at "Loading" when i scroll down after getting 30 results.Actually it should load 636 results.

This is my console [output](http://puu.sh/hC4eA/32d2cb167b.png).
This is my simulator which was at page 2 and stuck at loading.[Fig](http://puu.sh/hC4f6/e04beb1224.png)

No more duplicate results now,but why it dont load more data and stuck at page 2 when i scroll down to load more.

Comment: Do some debugging, log what page numbers are received and sent, tell us what they are. You need to localise the problem rather than just posting all your code and saying 'find my problem'

Comment: I update the code to less and simpler.I also got the problem but i dont know how to solve it.I think there is something wrong with "scrollViewDidScroll" method where user scroll down it load more results by calling "loadSegment".The problem is i am having 30 results of page 2 which is looping 1-15 & 1-15 and override the first page 1 15 results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why i am stucking at Page 2 with loading was,I dont set the "setLoadingState()" to false after i get the results from "didReceiveAPIResults()".So after appending the results into items Array,doing self.setLoadingState(false) solved the problem and it will enter to if(!self.loading) condition when user pull up to load more data from another page.

Thank you.I will not update the answer because i want all who like me to find out.

Answer (score 0):

In `didReceiveAPIResults` you are setting `self.items` and hen appending to it so you are deleting the old data and then duplicating it. You should simply be appending the new results onto the existing list.

Comment: Sir @Wain,Thank you for you suggestion and help.I am really appreciated that.I have updated the code.I have solved the data duplicate problem.But,why my program is stuck at "Loading" after i scroll down from page 2.

Comment: You need to log the page numbers it's using, I don't know what page details the server is returning. Is it always loading page 1 or does it say there aren't more pages to load. Debugging required...

Comment: Thanks @Wain, Debugging help me to find out.But, i used old school println() to find out because i cant use debugging well.I have solved it now.